# Value Error: Cannot convert string to float. CSV file opening with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to open a CSV dataset for decision tree learning. When I run the code it turns out with a value error. I think the problem is with the commas, but I don't know how to handle it.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn import metrics 

col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age', 'label']

pima = pd.read_csv(r'D:\MachinLearning\MyDataSets_Implementations\pima-indians-diabetes.csv', header=None, names=col_names)

pima.head()
```

some rows of dataset is like:

```
    Pregnancies,Glucose,BloodPressure,SkinThickness,Insulin,BMI,DiabetesPedigreeFunction,Age,Outcome
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1 1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1 1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
0,137,40,35,168,43.1,2.288,33,1 5,116,74,0,0,25.6,0.201,30,0
```

Comment: please, add a sample of your data

Comment: There is probably some formatting issues in there for instance in latin america for exapmle, to separate decimals a comma is used instead of a dot, and that would conflict with python's interpretability, hence 10,21 will be read as string instead of a float (10.21)

Comment: some rows of dataset is like:
Pregnancies,Glucose,BloodPressure,SkinThickness,Insulin,BMI,DiabetesPedigreeFunction,Age,Outcome
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
0,137,40,35,168,43.1,2.288,33,1
5,116,74,0,0,25.6,0.201,30,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get an error at all. It could help, to explicit define a separator in `pd.csv_read(... sep=",")`. You should also add `(..., skiprows=1)` in that function, to not read the fileheader as first datarow.

```
import pandas as pd
col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age', 'label']

csv_path = r'D:\MachinLearning\MyDataSets_Implementations\pima-indians-diabetes.csv'
pima = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=1, names=col_names, sep=",", skiprows=1)
print(pima.head())
```

Gives the output

```
pregnant  glucose  bp  ...  pedigree  age  label 
6 148 72 35 0   33.6 0.627 50      1 1       85  66  ...     0.351   31      0
8 183 64 0  0   23.3 0.672 32      1 1       89  66  ...     0.167   21      0
0 137 40 35 168 43.1 2.288 33      1 5      116  74  ...     0.201   30      0

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is solved with your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Please accept my answer in that case, thank you!